# Nodejs 8—destruction to already declared variables gives error

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6, destructuring

I have a function like that:

```
const exec = data => {
  let list, file;

  switch (data.action) {
    case A:
      { list } = getList(data);
      break;

    case B:
      { list } = getList(data);
      break;
  }
}
```

Node tells me:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token =
```

But as documented [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) (Section »Assignment separate from declaration«)

> A variable can be assigned its value via destructuring separate from the variable's declaration.

So, am I doing something wrong here, or is that a part of the ES6 spec, which node does not implement as documented?

Comment: @robertklep Cool! Thanks! Works! Put it in an answer and I will accept!

Comment: As you might have noticed, it was already answered ;D

Comment: @robertklep true! Wasn't here when when I wrote the comment…